# Inner join of 3 tables with row count

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, count, inner-join

I have 3 tables A,B and C as shown below.

[image: A]
[image: B]
[image: C]

All the 3 tables have a common `CUST_ID` column. And table A and B have 2 common columns `CUST_ID` and `A_ID`. I have to display the `NAME` from table `C`, Count of `Test_ID` from table `B` for each `CUST_ID` and `START` and `END` from table `A`. The expected result table is like,

[image: R]

I tried `inner join` like,

```
select C.Name ,A.Start,A.[End]
from
C
inner join
B
on C.CUST_ID = B.CUST_ID
inner join
A
on A.A_ID = B.A_ID and A.CUST_ID = B.CUST_ID
```

but its giving total 7 rows. How to display the count of `Test_ID` for east `CUST_ID` and display it in only 4 rows as shown in the expected result table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
    SELECT C.NAME, Tmp.Test_COUNT, A.START, A.END
    FROM C INNER JOIN A ON C.CUST_ID = A.CUST_ID
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT CUST_ID, A_ID, COUNT(*) AS Test_COUNT
        FROM B
        GROUP BY CUST_ID, A_ID
    ) Tmp ON Tmp.CUST_ID = A.CUST_ID AND Tmp.A_ID = A.A_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a subquery to obtain the test counts in table `B`, and join this table instead of joining `B` directly:

```
SELECT C.NAME, t.Test_COUNT, A.START, A.END
FROM C
INNER JOIN A
    ON C.CUST_ID = A.CUST_ID
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT A_ID, COUNT(*) AS Test_COUNT
    FROM B
    GROUP BY A_ID
) t
    ON t.A_ID = A.A_ID
```